# what code optimizations can roslyn provide

Tags: roslyn

I've started playing with Roslyn's syntax & semantic APIs. Haven't really digged hard yet but, is there any code optimization provided by semantic API like:

dead code elimination,
hoisting or
some sort of pointer analysis?
or other analyses?

I'm aware that roslyn provides methods for DFA and CFA but anything coming as a bonus to that?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built in to the API, but it is possible to build you own features like this using the APIs. I know of some people who have had success using Roslyn to identify and remove dead code for example.

Comment: Well, there are `RegionControlFlowAnalysis` and `RegionDataFlowAnalysis`, but they don't seem to offer much with regards to what the OP wants.

Comment: Thanks for getting back Kevin.

Comment: I am not sure if that is a separate question, but: Does that only mean, that Roslyn does not provide optimizations via the public API or does it also mean, that Roslyn does not optimize 1) the C# and 2) the emitted IL? Optimizer.cs in Roslyn  suggests, that at least *before* emitting IL the bound tree is optimized with regard to the subsequent IL emission. What is about optimizing the generated IL? Yes, the JIT compiler applies optimizations, but why not do IL optimizations before runtime when you have more time? Optimizations on the IL level (3 address code, ...) are what text books cover.

Comment: I can partially answer myself: Roslyn compiler must do some optimizations (according to language specification like constant folding) and from what I understood by skimming the source code these optimizations seem to be applied before/during IL generation, but not afterwards.
See also:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/15929